# Convert RGB 565 (Android Image) in to RGB 24(888) Image

Tags: android-image, image-conversion

I need convert an Android format (RGB 565) Image to RGB 24 format to avoid distraction when it displayed on computer. Any Suggestions? If someone can help me with an algorithm that'll be great.. Thanks